# Django models title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=100)

Tags: django

```
class PersonType(models.Model):
    """Person type model."""
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)
```

I wonder what is _('titile') do here for title. And also what is _('slug') do for slug?

Answer (score 2):

The first position argument of a `Field` subclass is the [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name) of that field: see the `__init__` constructor of `Field`:

```
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
   ...
   def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, ...)
       ...
```

The underscore `_` is the alias by convention for `ugettext_lazy`: you probably will see the following line of code:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/) offer a functionally equivalent snippet which uses a keyword argument rather than position args:

```
class MyThing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('This is the help text'))
```

This is a "lazy translation":

> These functions store a lazy reference to the string – not the actual translation. The translation itself will be done when the string is used in a string context, such as in template rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The _ is the name of a callable (function, callable object). It's usually used for the gettext function , for example in Django:

[Django Ducumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation)

you can use like this :

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext
equal output = gettext("Welcome to my site.")
```

Or like this

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
output = _("Welcome to my site.")
```

both of them used for **translation** and yot can use this value in template like this :

```
<title>{% trans "Welcome to my site." %}</title>

# Will print "Welcome to my site." if the current language is English
# "Bienvenue sur mon site." in French
# "به سایت من خوش آمدید." in Iran
```